# Archlinux bootlogo

Tags: boot, arch-linux

The logo displayed in the upper left corner of my boot screen in archlinux has changed from the arch logo to a tux.

Why could this be?
How do I change it?

Why are there two logos besides one another instead of just one?

Comment: [Two Tuxes indicate that you have a dual-core processor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux#Uses)  I'm not sure about the other points though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logo displayed in framebuffer mode actually compiled into the kernel. Check [this *arch-dev-public* thread](http://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2011-June/020603.html) and [this bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/24654).

You can hide the logos entirely by using [kernel mode setting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Mode_Setting) instead of framebuffer drivers, or [by adding `logo.nologo`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=482003#p482003) to the kernel command line.